# MailChimp AJAX API not calling API

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mailchimp

So I'm trying to integrate the API from MailChimp so that I won't redirect to the MailChimp website when subscribing. I'm using this [tutorial](http://kovalent.co/blog/mailchimp-api-example/). Whenever I try to subscribe, the website echo'd an error saying "'oh no, there has been a problem".

In the code on that site, it either means something went wrong with the API call or the AJAX function returned a non-200. The problem is that I can't find the problem in the code. I've probably inserted my information wrong in the code, but I can't find anything.

**JavaScript:**

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    $('form').submit(function (e) {
        //prevent the form from submitting via the browser redirect
        e.preventDefault();
        //grab attributes and values out of the form
        var data = {
            email: $('#mc-email').val()
        };
        var endpoint = $(this).attr('action');
        //make the ajax request
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST'
            , dataType: "json"
            , url: endpoint
            , data: data
        }).success(function (data) {
            if (data.id) {
                //successful adds will have an id attribute on the object
                alert('thanks for signing up');
            }
            else if (data.title == 'Member Exists') {
                //MC wil send back an error object with "Member Exists" as the title
                alert('thanks, but you are alredy signed up');
            }
            else {
                //something went wrong with the API call
                alert('oh no, there has been a problem');
            }
        }).error(function () {
            //the AJAX function returned a non-200, probably a server problem
            alert('oh no, there has been a problem');
        });
    });
});
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
//fill in these values for with your own information
$api_key = 'realapikey-us14';
$datacenter = 'us14';
$list_id = 'reallistid';
$email = $_POST['email'];
$status = 'subscribed';
if(!empty($_POST['status'])){
    $status = $_POST['status'];
}
$url = 'https://'.$datacenter.'.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/'.$list_id.'/members/';
$username = 'apikey';
$password = $api_key;
$data = array("email_address" => $email,"status" => $status);
$data_string = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$api_key");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $result;
?>
```

**HTML:**

```
<form action="./endpoint.php" method="POST" id="form mailchimp">
            <input type="hidden" name="u" value="VALUEFORLIST">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="LISTID">
            <input name="FNAME" class="popupname" type="text" value="" placeholder="Naam:" required/>
            <br>
            <input id="mc-email" name="EMAIL" class="popupemail" type="email" value="" placeholder="Email:" required/>
            <br>
            <input name="action" class="popupsubmit" type="submit" value="Aanmelden" class="submit" /> 
</form>
```

Comment: Please provide the HTML part too

Comment: I've added the HTML part @MûhámmàdYäsårK

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing the apikey as like `bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx5dxf-us10`, then the request will not be a success.

Try to pass the apikey by skipping the characters after the hyphen (like `bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx5dxf`) and check if it works.

In this case edit your php code from

```
$api_key = 'realapikey-us14';
```

to

```
$api_key = 'realapikey';
```

Comment: This, unfortunately, will still give me the "oh no, there has been a problem" error

Comment: When i generated the API code, it gave me the us14 by default

Comment: Could you please change one of the error message to "oh no, there has been a problem2" and check which error is showing?

Comment: I just changed the second one "non-200" to problem2 and it gave me that error. So it has something to do with the server i guess? Is the method I'm using still valid?

Comment: I've opened the browser console and it's giving me "jquery.js:9664 POST http://website.dev/endpoint.php 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: So the form action path `action="./endpoint.php"` is not correct. change it to the correct location of `endpoint.php` file.

Comment: I've corrected the path and it's still giving me the error. however the error doesn't show up in the console.

Comment: I've tested your code and it gave me 'thanks for signing up' and also the email got added to the list.

Comment: Weird, can you send the exact code(without the passkey etc ofcourse) to me so I can paste it in my editor and test it as well?